# Buildroot Build Issue

Tags: buildroot

I'm using Buildroot 2015.08.01.  I have this "weird" issue.  We use an "external tree" setup here.  I modified the .mk file to add/remove some libraries for the application to fix some unresolved symbol issues.  Changes are made in a /src directory. I do a -dirclean, verify the package is removed from the /output/build directory.  Then I make the package:  the modified sources are copied to the /output/build directory to do the build.  However, it seems buildroot is NOT using the modified .mk file in the build directory, as the changes made are not present on the Linker output line (i.e. still using the "old" link file list). I recall that buildroot seems to remember various names/symbols.  So how do I "flush" this so that buildroot will use the new link file list?
When I manually edit the console output with the updated list, and execute in this in the build directory, it works just fine.
Thank you for your insights into this "weird" issue.

Comment: Why don't you do a complete rebuild?

Comment: Without seeing your .mk file it is impossible to identify the cause, but probably you are not passing the libraries correctly to your package build system. Instead of copying the the linker output line, you should copy the call to `make` that Buildroot does and debug that.

Comment: As I stated, Buildroot "remembers" symbols.  I change the name of the link list and it worked just fine.  A complete rebuild takes 1 hr 40 min, I don't know if that would have "flushed" all the symbols.  An experiment to try.